# How can I prevent my Mac from selecting my Apple TV as an audio source by default

Tags: macos, audio, appletv

I own an Apple TV at home and have an Apple TV at work. I play audio through my home's stereo system fairly often. Whenever I get into the office while being previously connected to the Apple TV at home, my Mac connects to one of the Apple TVs at my office. How can I prevent my Mac from doing that?

Answer (score 1):

If you use airplay then this might work for you.

Change your Apple TV Name (Apple TV software version 6.1 and later)

Go to Settings > AirPlay > Apple TV Name > Custom.

Use this setting to change the name of the Apple TV to distinguish it from other Apple TVs on the same network.

Or in iTunes select the output

[image: iTunes output]